# PHPStorm - как включить поддержку JSX

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, jsx

Закрыл окно с предложением включить JSX в phpstorm - в результате показывает то, что вы видите на этой картинке:

[image: картинке]

Как включить поддержку jsx? Код работает и компилируется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно подчеркивает, phpstorm не знает, что вы пишете jsx. Для ide это выглядит, как кусок невалидного html в коде. Нужно включить поддержку jsx:

1. `ctrl` + `alt` + `s` - открываем настройки
2. Language & Frameworks
3. JavaScript
4. JavaScript language version
5. Выбираем версию - `React JSX`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Низкий поклон. Ваше решение работает! Вопрос решён и закрыт.